# How to install pillow (PIL) on mac OS 10.14.4?

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library, atom-editor

I'm trying to run images in python, which means I have to install pillow (since PIL is apparently outdated).(I'm running them in atom, so if this changes something in the process, please let me know).

I've installed xCode and homebrew, and pip appears to be downloaded, but `sudo pip install pillow` returns `-bash: pip: command not found` and `sudo -pip install pillow` then asks me for an ip, which I assume is ip address. When I put in my IP,  however, it tells me "Sorry, try again." I've tried installing it from homebrew by using `brew install brewsci/science/pillow`, which causes this: `Error: No previously deleted formula found. Error: No similarly named formulae found.`

Answer (score 0):

you try to run the following command to see Help:
`$ sudo easy_install pip
$ sudo pip install --upgrade pip
$ sudo pip install pillow`

Answer (score 0):

Pip is not installed.
Use

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`

then

`python get-pip.py`

to install pip.
You may have to run the last command with sudo privileges. You can replace `python` with `python3` or whatever python version you want to use.

Here is the installation manual for pip: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

After you have installed pip, you should use `sudo pip install pillow` (without a dash in front of pip).